# How to deploy Managed Elastic Cloud to Azure with ARM template/Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, elastic-cloud

I have not found a way to deploy Elastic Cloud (managed elasticsearch, kibana, logstash) to Azure using ARM template or the CLI.

This is the one I would like to deploy:
https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/elastic.ec-azure?tab=overview

I cannot use the portal at my company, hence I am looking for any programmatic way Elastic Cloud can be deployed to Azure.

Can anybody push me to the right direction? I only found the self-managed elastic ARM template - and not the elastic cloud (managed) template that I need.

Comment: are you talking about that: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/elastic.ec-azure?tab=overview ?

Comment: exactly! let me edit the question! @Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible from the Azure PowerShell/CLI/ARM to deploy a *managed service*.  At this time you can only deploy marketplace *images* from PowerShell/CLI/ARM.  I would suggest reaching out to Elastic to see if they can sign you up outside of the portal.  See snippet from the online docs below.

In case your Elastic Cloud resource is not fully set up and you’re not able to access the Support page, you can always send an email to **support@elastic.co**.

Comment: "See snippet from the online docs below." -- @KenWMSFT could you share the docs please?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-billing-azure.html